# What kind of research will go in nuclear fusion power once the commercial power plant is designed and implemented?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

once the commercial nuclear power plant is built for electricity production , after this what kind of research does scientists do in nuclear fusion power. Why I am asking this question is ITER is planning to build the fusion reactor in 2030s , So after what research does nuclear fusion scientists do ?

Answer (score 1):

The construction of [ITER](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/0/a/70adfaa8b72ecb33eabf5a17da159d1c.png) is taking so long not only because of the complications of size but also  of the great number of physics disciplines covered under "nuclear fusion scientists". Starting  from plasma physicists, who will continue to do research in plasma physics to electronic engineering, materials science is also important. When ITER is finished and the new reactor given over to nuclear engineering each scientist in his/her discipline will continue doing research in their field of expertise, or retire :) since it has taken so long.

In addition, there are other lines of research into fusion, like [inertial fusion,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nucene/finert.html) which requires laser physics research interests and if it succeeds might be an alternate fusion source, which may still be ongoing after ITER finishes.

Plus there might be some smart new thinking and research going on in various laboratories that might be more efficient and advantageous in the long run they could join.

Comment: Thanks anna v,I can understand your last two points but can't able to comprehend your first point since the research you mentioned  (Starting from plasma physicists, who will continue to do research in plasma physics to electronic engineering, materials science is also important) , how this will helpful for fusion power.

Comment: Understanding the plasma better will surely improve the performance of next generation fusion reactors, the same for the pertinent entineering and research on materials, they certainly have room for improvement always).